# Modify Bootstrap files or Write on top of it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3. Ok no problem so far, but, there's a but...I don't know what is the right approach when it comes to alter bootstraps's core css code. So for instance I want to design a new theme, let's say for my own site, and I want to do that using Bootstrap 3, but when it comes to prettiness bootstrap it's like a 3-4 out of 10.

Should I tweak bootstrap files with my own css styling OR Should I build on top of bootstrap and, well, having unused css properties in bootstrap file that I overwrite in my own "style.css".

And I'm not talking about Bootstrap Customize option on site. There are not so many things I could change.

Comment: You should see for yourself which choice suits you best.

Comment: Well it's more time consuming to write on top of it than to just simply modify what I need. But in the same time I like the idea to have a personal style sheet, arranged how I like...so see? there is the problem...It's hard to decide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely build on top of Bootstrap, create a new css file. It is better not to touch bootstrap at all, and have it act as it is intended when you need it to.

Comment: I guess you just helped me decide the best option...so thank you.

Comment: @user3932954 Do you have any arguments for this answer, or is it just personal preference? I don't see a problem in making small edits/improvements (depends on how you look at it) to the Bootstrap file(s).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to add/remove components desired and customize Less variables to define colors, sizes and more inside your custom CSS stylesheets. Bootstrap's customizer finally will generate your csutom javascript & style files with desired components.
2. If you use css preprocessors like LESS or Sass you can do it by changing variables' values in your editor. Bootstrap's default preprocessor is LESS, but there is also available [Sass version](//github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

Comment: 1. As I already said in my post, the customize option on bootstrap's page it's pretty basic, but helpful for the navbar customization, for instance. I just wanted more advanced control over their styling. As for nr 2. It's to much work...